# How to use placeholders outside of permalink in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I'm making a jekyll site to showcase my projects and I'm trying to make a custom variable that links to the source code using placeholders but it's not working

```
title: api
author: cabiste
source-code: https://github.com/:author/:title/
```

output for `post.source-code`: `https://github.com/:author/:title/`

is that not possible or is there a way to convert it?